# Настройка Photoshop перед вёрсткой.

Tags: photoshop

1. Как сделать так, что бы размер пикселя в браузере и в Photoshop был одинаковый? Создаётся ощущения, что в обеих вещах размер разный.
2. Нужно ли ещё что - то настраивать в Photoshop перед вёрсткой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Про размер пикселя порадовали однозначно))
Фотошоп нужен только для нарезки отдельных элементов для верстки. Верстается всё в браузере. 
Включаем аддон https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/pixel-perfect/ и накладываем на фон картинку. По ней уже и размещаем все элементы.

Но pixel perfect в ФФ вроде не стабильный, используйте Google Chrome, он и для него есть.https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/perfectpixel-by-welldonec/dkaagdgjmgdmbnecmcefdhjekcoceebi?hl=ru